# You should set the `loop_var` value in the `loop_control` option for the task to something else to avoid variable

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook, ansible-galaxy

My environment:

```
# cat /etc/debian_version
11.7
# ansible-playbook --version
ansible-playbook [core 2.13.1]
  config file = None
  configured module search path = ['/root/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/ansible
  ansible collection location = /root/.ansible/collections:/usr/share/ansible/collections
  executable location = /usr/local/bin/ansible-playbook
  python version = 3.9.2 (default, Feb 28 2021, 17:03:44) [GCC 10.2.1 20210110]
  jinja version = 3.1.2
  libyaml = True
#
```

The following task is part of my Ansible role:

```
- name: _file - state:absent
  ansible.builtin.file:
    path: "{{ item.path }}"
    state: absent
  loop: "{{ find.files | flatten }}"
  register: file
  when: find.matched is defined and find.matched != 0
```

yet, I've noticed a warning message:

> [WARNING]: TASK: XYZ : _file - state:absent: The loop variable 'item' is already in use. You should set the `loop_var` value in the `loop_control` option for the task to something else to avoid variable
> collisions and unexpected behavior.

after reading some:

- [Defining inner and outer variable names with loop_var](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_loops.html#defining-inner-and-outer-variable-names-with-loop-var)
- [Adding controls to loops](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_loops.html#adding-controls-to-loops)

I modified my task to something like this:

```
- name: _file - state:absent
  ansible.builtin.file:
    path: "{{ item.path }}"
    state: absent
  loop: "{{ find.files | flatten }}"
  loop_control:
    label: "{{ item.path }}"
    loop_var: find
  register: file
  when: find.matched is defined and find.matched != 0
```

this task is being called twice within my role, while first time it works fine, second time it fails

```
TASK [XYZ : _file - state:absent] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
[WARNING]: TASK: XYZ : _file - state:absent: The loop variable 'find' is already in use. You should set the `loop_var` value in the `loop_control` option for the task to something else to avoid variable
collisions and unexpected behavior.
failed: [127.0.0.1] (item=None) => {"ansible_loop_var": "find", "changed": false, "find": {"atime": 1683511713.8529496, "checksum": "ecd34202c34bf761e4c2c9800a39e18dffad5d9e", "ctime": 1683511714.972948, "dev": 2049, "gid": 0, "gr_name": "root", "inode": 150677, "isblk": false, "ischr": false, "isdir": false, "isfifo": false, "isgid": false, "islnk": false, "isreg": true, "issock": false, "isuid": false, "mode": "0644", "mtime": 1683511714.972948, "nlink": 1, "path": "tmp/FILE.CSV", "pw_name": "root", "rgrp": true, "roth": true, "rusr": true, "size": 642, "uid": 0, "wgrp": false, "woth": false, "wusr": true, "xgrp": false, "xoth": false, "xusr": false}, "msg": "Failed to template loop_control.label: 'item' is undefined", "skip_reason": "Conditional result was False"}
```

Please advise.

Comment: You should provide the outer loop as well. [edit] the question and make it [mre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear why you need the (undocumented) outer loop that registers the variable *item*. For example, given the tree

```bash
shell> tree /tmp/test
/tmp/test
├── file1
├── file2
└── file3
```

the play below

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: localhost

  tasks:

    - find:
        paths: /tmp/test
      register: find

    - file:
        path: "{{ item.path }}"
        state: absent
      loop: "{{ find.files }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.path }}"
```

gives running in *--check --diff* mode

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook -CD pb.yml

PLAY [localhost] ******************************************************************************

TASK [find] ***********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [file] ***********************************************************************************
--- before
+++ after
@@ -1,2 +1,2 @@
 path: /tmp/test/file3
-state: file
+state: absent

changed: [localhost] => (item=/tmp/test/file3)
--- before
+++ after
@@ -1,2 +1,2 @@
 path: /tmp/test/file2
-state: file
+state: absent

changed: [localhost] => (item=/tmp/test/file2)
--- before
+++ after
@@ -1,2 +1,2 @@
 path: /tmp/test/file1
-state: file
+state: absent

changed: [localhost] => (item=/tmp/test/file1)

PLAY RECAP ************************************************************************************
localhost: ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

---

Notes:

- If you define *loop_var* use it. The task below gives the same results

```yaml
- file:
    path: "{{ my_loop_var.path }}"
    state: absent
  loop: "{{ find.files }}"
  loop_control:
    label: "{{ my_loop_var.path }}"
    loop_var: my_loop_var
```

- The condition below is redundant. Remove it. When nothing is found (*find.matched: 0*) the list of files is empty (*fined.files: []*) and the loop will be skipped anyway

```yaml
  when: find.matched is defined and find.matched != 0
```

- There is nothing to flatten if *find* is the registered variable of the module *find*. The filter *flatten* can be removed

```yaml
  loop: "{{ find.files }}"
```

Comment: i completely misunderstood how that suppose to work, but i've got it now) thank you! btw, when is used to make sure to run role to the end, without errors (skips are okay).